# Proving that a graph is connected?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that this graph is connected given the provided information.

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph with $n \geq 2$ vertices. Prove that if $δ(G) \geq \frac{n}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

I can see from testing a few examples that it's definitely true. As for the actual proof, I'm stuck:

If we have $n$ vertices, then we have at most $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges. However, I'm still not seeing what the minimum vertex degree has to do with the number of edges at any other vertices, and especially in showing that we have enough edges to guarantee connectedness.

I don't feel like I'm approaching this problem the right way. If anyone could help, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: When in doubt, go back to the basics! What do you get by trying to apply the definition of a connected graph? How could you find a path between any two vertices u,v?

Comment: Well, both vertices would need a degree of at least one, and every vertex on the path's "interior" would need a degree of at least two in order to exist. I'm still not sure how I can validly differentiate between the veritces in a proof though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contradiction: suppose the graph is not connected, then it has at the very least $2$ connected components, so the size of the smallest component is at most $\frac{n}{2}$ Meaning the degree of a vertex in that component is at most $\frac{n}{2}-1$ meaning the minimum degree is at most $\frac{n}{2}-1$. Thus a graph with minimum degree at least $\frac{n}{2}$ must be connected.

Comment: Thank you, this explanation is very clear and makes sense. I'm going to accept it, but I would like to try and figure out the intuition myself by progressing on the other two paths proposed here first.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $u$ and $v$ be any two vertices. Let $N(u)$ be the vertex $u$ together with its neighbors, and define $N(v)$ similarly. Is it possible that $N(u)\cap N(v)=\varnothing$?

Comment: Yes, if $u$ and $v$ are on disjoint connected components?

Comment: @Jonson: It actually isn’t: there simply aren’t enough vertices. But I’ve modified the hint slightly to make it a little stronger.

Comment: Hmm. So, if there's any overlap at all then the sets share a neighbor, and if a neighbor exists between these two sets then they are clearly connected together, and therefore the entire graph is connected. Assuming we're trying to prevent that from happening, we want to contain all of the connections inside each of the sets, so we can have a degree of at most $\frac{n}{2} - 1$. We have more than that, so they must be connected...

That makes sense to me, but what happens regarding points not immediate neighbors of $u$ and $v$? Aren't they in neither set?

Comment: @Jonson: You don’t care about them. The point is that for any vertices $u$ and $v$, $N(u)\cap N(v)\ne\varnothing$, so either they are adjacent, or there is a vertex $z$ adjacent to both of them. In either case there’s a path from $u$ to $v$. Since this is true for all pairs of vertices, the graph is connected.

Comment: Okay, I see from some more drawings that the possibilties I was thinking about aren't actually possible given the minimum degree stipulation. I was imagining something like a really long graph where the path between $u$ and $v$ had to go through more than one adjacent vertex. But this isn't possible. Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: @Jonson: You’re welcome!